# cmd window and shutdown not running

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, ctypes

hello all I am python programmer
I made a program with spyder IDE with python 3.7.0
when I ran this program the program didn't execute the desired action
that is they don't shutdown this pc or lock it and doesn't open cmd
can you show me the mistake and if possible correct the code by typing below

```
import os
import ctypes
command = "cmd"
print ("select from any commands")
print ('1.open CMD')
print ('2.shutdown pc')
print ('3.restart pc')
print ('4.lock pc')
choice = input()
if choice == 1:     #starts command prompt
    os.system(command);
if choice == 2:     #trigger shutdown
    os.system("shutdown -p");
if choice == 3:     #trigger restart
    os.system("shutdown -r");
if choice == 4:     #trigger lockscreem
    ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[Python 3]: **input**(*[prompt]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a **string**. When comparing a string with an integer (e.g. `"1" == 1`), **the result will always be *False***.

To fix your problem, either:

- Convert **each** of the 4 values (used in comparisons) to a string, by placing its value between quotes e.g:

  ```py
  if choice == "1":
  ```
- Convert *input*'s result to an integer e.g.:

  ```py
  choice = int(input())
  ```

  but you'll have to enclose that in a *try* / *except* block (to avoid program crash if user doesn't input an integer)

**Notes** (to improve your code):

- When calling functions, **always** check their return value (which may be an error indicator)
- Since the 4 are choices, then they are *mutually exclusive*, meaning that only one (or none) will be executed. As a consequence, you could replace each of the **last 3 *if*** clauses by an ***elif***, so if the program entered one branch, it won't test for the ones that follow it

  - You could also add a final ***else*** clause, where you could let the user know that none of the choices executed (the value entered was different than all of them)
- Instead of the 5 *print* statements (for the menu), you could just pass one string (you'll have to format it) to *input*:

  ```py
  choice = input("select from any commands:\n  1.open CMD\n  2.shutdown pc\n  3.restart pc\n  4.lock pc\n")
  ```
- For better flexibility, you could use the *subprocess* module (instead of `os.system`) to execute external commands
- *ctypes* is a tricky topic, and although if for this case things are fine, for more complex ones (e.g. calling a function with parameters) it might not work as expected. There are many examples (on this site and on others) showing how to deal with such cases
- When program doesn't work as expected, you could always *debug* it, or at least print the variables involved, and thus increase the chances of figuring the problem yourself

Comment: thanks very much the program delivered the desired results

Comment: can oyou check my second problem

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as a solution to the question, so other users are aware that it solved it.